# Split an array by key

Tags: php

I have an array with the following keys:

```
Array
{
    [vegetable_image] =>
    [vegetable_name] =>
    [vegetable_description] =>
    [fruit_image] =>
    [fruit_name] =>
    [fruit_description] =>
}
```

and I would like to split them based on the prefix (vegetable_ and fruit_), is this possible?

Currently, I'm trying out `array_chunk()` but how do you store them into 2 separate arrays?

```
[vegetables] => Array { [vegetable_image] ... }
[fruits] => Array { [fruit_image] ... }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$fruits = array();
$vegetables = array();

foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    if(strpos($k,'fruit_') !== false)
        $fruits[$k] = $v;
    elseif(strpos($k,'vegetable_') !== false)
        $vegetables[$k] = $v;
}
```

As an example see: http://ideone.com/uNi54B

Answer (score 1):

Out of the Box

```
function splittArray($base_array, $to_split, $delimiter='_') {
   $out = array();
   foreach($to_split as $key) {
      $search = $key.delimiter;
      foreach($base_array as $ok=>$val) {
        if(strpos($ok,$search)!==false) {
           $out[$key][$ok] = $val;
        }
   }
   return $out;
 }

 $new_array = splittArray($array,array('fruit','vegetable'));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/array_reduce)

```
$array     = ['foo_bar' => 1, 'foo_baz' => 2, 'bar_fee' => 6, 'bar_feo' => 9, 'baz_bee' => 7];
$delimiter = '_';

$result = array_reduce(array_keys($array), function ($current, $key) use ($delimiter) {
        $splitKey                = explode($delimiter, $key);
        $current[$splitKey[0]][] = $key;
        return $current;
}, []);
```

Check the [fiddle](http://3v4l.org/rZVPk#v540)

Only one thins remains: you are using different forms (like `"vegetable_*"` -> `"vegetables"`). PHP is not smart enough to substitute language (that would be English language in this case) transformations like that. But if you like, you may create array of valid forms for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `explode()`

```
$arrVeg = array();
$arrFruit = array();
$finalArr = array();

foreach($array as $k => $v){
  $explK = explode('_',$k);
  if($explK[0] == 'vegetable'){
     $arrVeg[$k] = $v;
  } elseif($explK[0] == 'fruit') {
     $arrFruit[$k] = $v;
  }
}

$finalArr['vegetables'] = $arrVeg;
$finalArr['fruits'] = $arrFruit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use simple PHP array traversing and [substr()](http://php.net/substr) function.

```
<?php
$arr = array();
$arr['vegetable_image'] = 'vegetable_image';
$arr['vegetable_name'] = 'vegetable_name';
$arr['vegetable_description'] = 'vegetable_description';
$arr['fruit_image'] = 'fruit_image';
$arr['fruit_name'] = 'fruit_name';
$arr['fruit_description'] = 'fruit_description';

$fruits = array();
$vegetables = array();
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    if (substr($k, 0, 10) == 'vegetable_') {
        $vagetables[$k] = $v;
    }
    else if (substr($k, 0, 6) == 'fruit_') {
        $fruits[$k] = $v;
    }
}
print_r($fruits);
print_r($vagetables);
```

[Working Example](http://codepad.org/bhwpKyLW)